# ScaffoldColumn attribute on type object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, scaffolding

It seems that to skip a member to come on a View you can set ScaffoldColumn attribute to false in your model

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public object Id { get; set; }
```

but here i see that Id is of object type. Is this the only way? I tried with

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

but it didn't work. How can i prevent scaffolding on a primitive type e.g. int,long etc.

**Edit**

I have define my model as

```
public class Department
{
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]        
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
        [StringLength(25)]
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller having action `Create`. When i right click on create action and select add view and create a strongly type view with this model it creates a view but also adds a textbox for Id

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)%>
```

which i suppose it shouldn't have

Comment: `ScaffoldColumn(false)` *does* work with primitive types. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Craig is there any other way/hack i can make it work?

Comment: `ScaffoldColumn(false)` *is* the correct way. Like I said, your problem is in code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ScaffoldColumn` only changes the behavior of methods like `Html.DisplayForModel()` which actually use [the default templated views system introduced in MVC 2](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html). It *does not* affect the Visual Studio wizards that ship with MVC.

To change that, you need to edit the T4 templates, [somewhat like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2009/03/04/asp-net-mvc-tip-add-a-new-t4-template-for-making-mvccontrib-grid-helper-component.aspx).

I wouldn't bother, though. If you want scaffolding in MVC 2, I think it's better to use default templated views than the "Add View" scaffolding, which is code generation.

Comment: marking it as the answer for the fact it works for method like Html.DisplayForModel(). But couldn't get why it behaves properly when it type is set to object